# issues when creating a basic server using nodejs

Tags: node.js, server

(everything i follow the tutorial)

I try to create a basic server in my computer by using nodejs, the code is like below:

```
var http = require('http');

function onRequest(request, response){
console.log("A user made a request" + request.url);
response.write(200, {"Context-Type":"text/plain"});
response.write("Here is data");
response.end();
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
console.log("Server is now running.....");
```

And I go to website enter localhost:8888, The result is like below:

C:\Program Files\nodejs\nodejs>node server.js
Server is now running.....
A user made a request/
_http_outgoing.js:433
    throw new TypeError('first argument must be a string or Buffer');
          ^
TypeError: first argument must be a string or Buffer
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.write (_http_outgoing.js:433:11)
    at Server.onRequest (C:\Program Files\nodejs\nodejs\server.js:5:11)
    at Server.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncoming [as onIncoming] (_http_server.js:491:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:111:23)
    at Socket.socketOnData (_http_server.js:343:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:126:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:538:20)

The webpage is saying that the webpage is not available.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not writing the head properly, you should use the `http` method `writeHead`. Like this:

```
var http = require('http');

function onRequest(request, response){
    console.log("A user made a request" + request.url);

    //Here is your mistake, you have "write" instead of "writeHead" and I think you should use "Content" instead of "Context"
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/plain"});

    response.write("Here is data");
    response.end();
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
console.log("Server is now running.....");
```